# Change the doctype of an aspx page dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, doctype

We use master pages in our web application, the doctype is defined in the master page.

On one of the pages I need to change the doctype, or else a third-party control renders incorrectly.

How can I change the doctype of only that certain page without affecting the rest of the pages?

Answer (score 5):

By far the simplest way is to make another copy of your master page, change the doctype in that and have this page use the new master.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it would work but

You can reset the content type with

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/html";
```

Then write your doctype type

```
Response.Write(<new doc-type>);
```

But you will also loose all meta headers and such, you're probably better off with the other solution provided by Chris Lively...

Answer (score 1):

Have you used an ASP Literal control?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:literal runat="server" id="docType"></asp:literal>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
```

Then in the Page_Load, you could:

```
this.docType.Text = {your doctype-string here};
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too....

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<!DOCTYPE HTML>" + Environment.NewLine);
        HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
        base.Render(textWriter);
        writer.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
```